# Kryo java.lang.UnspportedOperationException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kryo, bigdata

I am trying to use Kryo in spark for [the SAMRecord class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.seqdoop/htsjdk/1.118/htsjdk/samtools/SAMRecord.java), but getting the error shown at runtime. I don't understand what this error means, can anyone explain? What do I need to change for Kryo to work with this? The problem is with the member variable `mAlignmentBlocks` of type `List<AlignmentBlock>`. Does Kryo have a problem with such lists?

Note that I have registered both `AlignmentBlock` and `SAMRecord` by using the following code:

```
kryo.register(classOf[AlignmentBlock])
kryo.register(classOf[SAMRecord])
```

And the error I get is this:

> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>       Serialization trace:
>       mAlignmentBlocks (htsjdk.samtools.SAMRecord)
>               at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer$ObjectField.read(FieldSerializer.java:626)
>               at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:221)
>               at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
>               at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:42)
>               at com.twitter.chill.Tuple2Serializer.read(TupleSerializers.scala:33)
>               at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
>               at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:228)
>               at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:171)
>               at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:201)
>               at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:198)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
>               at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>               at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
>               at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>               at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)
>               at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:45)
>               at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:89)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>               at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)

Answer (score -1):

you are calling a method on a class that implementing an interface but the implementation of this method is not present.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I didn't understand what you said. Implementation of which class is not present? You mean the List<AlignmentBlock> class? If so, how can I add that?

Comment: i don't know kryo and i now that my explication can be abstract... found the method you call and that is giving you this exception. see its source code. i can't do ot myself as im on my phone...

Comment: seems to be in kryo. sorry i can help you more because don't knowing more about kryo. put the code where you call kryo to serialize